# How to read xml node title and it's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have following `xml` and want to parse it and read every `node value` and `node title`.
I can read the `value` but can't read the `node title`. I used `reader.Name` but it always returns `empty string`. How can I Read node title too?

```
string ExceptionDetails="<names><FirstName>John</FirstName><SecondName>White</SecondName></names>";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(ExceptionDetails)))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
       {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
             if (reader.HasValue)
             {               
                sb.Append()+":"; //Read tag title
                sb.Append(reader.Value); sb.Append("<br/>");                      
             }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

result:

```
FirstName:John
SecondName:white
```

Comment: why dont just use reader.Name and reader.value

Comment: I used it but it returns empty sting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XmlReader.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the name of the current node. In case of an element, this is the tag name. In order to remember the last tag name before the text, you need to store it in a variable before you add it to the StringBuilder:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string ExceptionDetails="<names><FirstName>John</FirstName><SecondName>White</SecondName></names>";
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(ExceptionDetails)))
        {
            string tagName = string.Empty;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                   tagName = reader.Name;
               else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
               {               
                    sb.Append(tagName);
                    sb.Append(":"); //Read tag title
                    sb.Append(reader.Value); sb.Append("<br/>");                      
               }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can run the sample [here](http://ideone.com/56Gs06).

Comment: It doesn't give me the result I mentioned. I confused.

Comment: @RaymondMorphy: what's the difference? The `<br/>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Your XML);
    var elements = doc.Descendants( "names" );
    Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
       string key = elements[i].Attributes["key"].Value.ToString();
       string value = elements[i].Attributes["value"].Value.ToString();
       keyValues.Add(key,value);
    }
```